# Performance of array lookup vs bitshift

Tags: java, arrays, performance, bitwise-operators

For an implementation of Othello (Reversi), I precomputed powers of two to be looked up in an array. Today, while trying to optimize for speed, this struck me as a premature optimization since I previously assumed lookup to be faster and never actually made a benchmark.

Here's how i precalculate the powers of two:

```
private static final long[] POWERS_OF_TWO = LongStream.range(0L, NUM_SQUARES)
                                                      .map(l -> 1L << l)
                                                      .toArray();
```

And this is how a callsite might look

```
final long newSelf = self | cur | POWERS_OF_TWO[i];
```

Now, the alternative would be to directly compute the power of two at the callsite:

```
final long newSelf = self | cur | (1L << i);
```

Which method is faster?

Answer (score 2):

I decided to write a JMH benchmark to test my issue.

## The Benchmark

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.Main;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Fork;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Measurement;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Warmup;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.RunnerException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;

@Warmup(iterations = 3)
@Measurement(iterations = 3)
@Fork(value = 1)
public class LookupVsShift {
    private static final int NUM_SQUARES = 64;
    private static final long[] POWERS_OF_TWO = LongStream.range(0L, NUM_SQUARES)
                                                          .map(l -> 1L << l)
                                                          .toArray();
    private static final int N = 1_000_000;

    @Benchmark
    public long testLookupUnroll() {
        long sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[58]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[23]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[55]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[56]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[52]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[38]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[49]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[36]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[9]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[7]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[19]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[54]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[37]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[4]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[35]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[8]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[40]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[33]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[43]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[13]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[14]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[3]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[20]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[63]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[29]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[18]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[45]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[22]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[57]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[26]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[24]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[10]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[16]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[15]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[46]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[32]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[17]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[48]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[41]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[39]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[12]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[51]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[21]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[0]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[50]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[44]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[2]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[60]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[34]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[31]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[30]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[53]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[61]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[1]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[27]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[62]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[25]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[28]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[11]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[5]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[6]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[42]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[59]) & 0x3f;
            sum += (i + POWERS_OF_TWO[47]) & 0x3f;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long testShiftUnroll() {
        long sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            sum += 1L << (i + 35) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 52) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 55) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 57) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 38) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 13) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 36) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 19) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 7) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 48) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 8) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 0) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 45) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 2) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 14) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 44) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 31) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 6) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 25) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 18) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 34) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 41) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 37) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 32) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 1) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 53) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 9) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 16) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 62) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 4) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 12) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 46) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 17) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 29) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 63) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 51) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 21) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 24) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 49) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 40) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 58) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 59) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 33) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 61) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 56) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 42) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 5) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 23) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 22) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 43) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 60) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 15) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 11) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 27) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 30) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 54) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 10) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 3) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 50) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 28) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 47) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 20) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 26) & 0x3f;
            sum += 1L << (i + 39) & 0x3f;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, RunnerException {
        Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

## Results

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:02:07

Benchmark                        Mode  Cnt   Score    Error  Units
LookupVsShift.testLookupUnroll  thrpt    3  23,072 ±  7,674  ops/s
LookupVsShift.testShiftUnroll   thrpt    3  20,834 ± 16,676  ops/s
```

## Result

I feel like now this benchmark compares the two relatively fairly and with insufficient overhead to make the difference negligible. As it looks now, lookup seems to be a bit faster again. I think it's just due to what Danny_ds said, it's hard to design an accurate benchmark for such fast operations...

Comment: Change `RESULTS.add(sum)` to simply `return sum` and remove `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` as it's not used. Will it change the results?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to remove the `Random` instance from a previous iteration of the benchmark. No measurable difference though. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: If `testLookup` has more `ops/s` doesn't it make it faster than `testShift`?

Comment: My initial guess was same as yours, RAM access should be slower. Maybe write a benchmark where you traverse the lookup array randomly and not in order? This should invalidate caches :)

Comment: You could *maybe* optimize if you would not use intermediate variables and directly do all the computation in a single line and assign it to the `sum`

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I've added random access both via `Random` and via multiplying by a large prime number and using modulo, and with random access, it looks like the two methods about equally fast.

Comment: Instead of `% NUM_SQUARES` you could use the faster `&& 0x3f` as long as `NUM_SQUARES` is 64.

Comment: You mean `&`, not `&&`, but yes, good point. Did that, more ops/s but still a bit of a difference.

Comment: Strange, looks like shifting is again slower now.

Comment: Yeah.. I don't know... Obviously this is very difficult to benchmark accurately.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this benchmark: 1) an explicit loop is written manually instead of relying on JMH internal benchmarking loop; 2) two methods measure different functions: `i+2ⁿ` vs. `2ⁱ⁺ⁿ`; 3) it uses constants which can be folded by JIT-compiler instead of `@State` variables.

Comment: @apangin I realize it's not ideal, this already went through a lot of iterations, even with input from other users. Can you suggest a benchmark that will yield accurate results?

Answer (score 2):

You will need a better test than the one in your answer.

Let's have a look at the loop code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    final int idx = i % NUM_SQUARES;
    final long value = 1L << idx;
    sum += value;
}
```

Shifting is a really fast operation for the cpu - it should be at least as fast as `++` or `+=`. So if we look at the code we have the loop counter (`i++`), the `sum +=` and the branch (`i < N`). The `%` probably takes 10 to 20 times as much cpu cycles as the shift.

So for better testing and timing of the shift operation, I would remove the `%` and get all 64 powers of two inside the loop in random order (for the array). Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sum += 1L << 4;
    sum += 1L << 7;
    sum += 1L << 1;
    // and so on
}
```

For the array version you could use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    sum += POWER_OF_TWOS[4];
    sum += POWER_OF_TWOS[7];
    sum += POWER_OF_TWOS[1];
    // and so on
}
```

Or using variables instead of constants and bitmasking instead of %:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    final int idx = i & 0x3f;
    sum += 1L << idx;
}

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    final int idx = i & 0x3f;
    sum += POWER_OF_TWOS[idx];
}
```

Or if the optimizer could be tricked with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    final int idx = 0;
    sum += 1L << (idx + 4);
    sum += 1L << (idx + 17);
    // ...
}
```

Anyway, a shift operation is really fast and should be a no-brainer to use over an array with precomputerd values.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very good point. Benchmarking is tricky as usual. What would you suggest as a Benchmark for lookup? Surely, if just go `POWER_OF_TWOS[0]` to `POWER_OF_TWOS[63]`, the JVM might optimize those calls? Is mixing them up really enough to stop optimization as you say?

Comment: @Marv That's why I would call them random: `sum += POWER_OF_TWOS[19]`, `sum += POWER_OF_TWOS[7]`, and so on.

Comment: @Marv Yes, the JVM or compiler could (and should) optimize the array access wit constant index. Same for the shift with constant. To test with variables you could use bitmasking instead of `%`.

Comment: In the shift example you provided, the shifts are getting replaced by constants by `javac` (see my answer).

Comment: @Marv Yes, it will be hard to test such a fast operation without the overhead of other operations. See my updated answer for some examples.